# BlockUi not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, asp.net-4.0, jquery-blockui

We have used the `BlockUi` Jquery for showing progress event in our page.

Below is `js` code that included in page

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var UpdPanelsIds = null;
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);


    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //  alert('hi');
        //        var updpnl = sender._postBackSettings.panelID;
        //        alert(updpnl);

        UpdPanelsIds = args.get_updatePanelsToUpdate();
        UpdPanelsIds = UpdPanelsIds.toString().split('$').join('_');


        $('#' + UpdPanelsIds + '').block({ message: $('#divBlock') });

    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $('#' + UpdPanelsIds + '').unblock();
    }

</script>
```

Below is the `div` , which is blocked and unblocked using the `BlockUI` jquery

```
 <div style="display: none;height:70px;width:70px;" id="divBlock">
                    <img id="ctl00_Image1" src="../Images/Loading_Trans.gif" alt="Loading.." style="border-width:0px;" />
               </div>
```

this works fine with other browsers , but in IE , it just work for first request and after then in all subsequent request, the `div` shows up with the background , but `image` with in `div` do not show up

Any body have any idea for this issue??

Answer (score 1):

try add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
           .
           .
```